# AssertionError: INTERNAL: No default project is specified

Tags: python-2.7, airflow

New to airflow. Trying to run the sql and store the result in a BigQuery table.

Getting following error. Not sure where to setup the default_rpoject_id.

Please help me.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 28, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 585, in test
    ti.run(ignore_task_deps=True, ignore_ti_state=True, test_mode=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1374, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py", line 82, in execute
    self.allow_large_results, self.udf_config, self.use_legacy_sql)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 228, in run_query
    default_project_id=self.project_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook.py", line 917, in _split_tablename
    assert default_project_id is not None, "INTERNAL: No default project is specified"
AssertionError: INTERNAL: No default project is specified
```

Code:

```
sql_bigquery = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='sql_bigquery',
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        allow_large_results=True,
        bql='''
            #standardSQL
                SELECT ID, Name, Group, Mark, RATIO_TO_REPORT(Mark) OVER(PARTITION BY Group) AS percent FROM `tensile-site-168620.temp.marks`
                ''',
        destination_dataset_table='temp.percentage',
        dag=dag
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I finally fixed this problem by simply adding the `bigquery_conn_id='bigquery'` parameter in the BigQueryOperator task, after running the code below in a separate python script.

Apparently you need to specify your project ID in Admin -> Connection in the Airflow UI. You must do this as a JSON object such as "project" : "".

Personally I can't get the webserver working on GCP so this is unfeasible. There is a programmatic solution here:

```
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.settings import Session

session = Session()
gcp_conn = Connection(
    conn_id='bigquery',
    conn_type='google_cloud_platform',
    extra='{"extra__google_cloud_platform__project":"<YOUR PROJECT HERE>"}')
if not session.query(Connection).filter(
        Connection.conn_id == gcp_conn.conn_id).first():
    session.add(gcp_conn)
    session.commit()
```

These suggestions are from [a similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39178629/setting-up-airflow-with-bigquery-operator)

Comment: You can also create connections via the CLI which makes automating them possible: http://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/v1-9-stable/cli.html#connections

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error when running airflow locally. My solution is to add a the following connection string as a environment variable:

```
AIRFLOW_CONN_BIGQUERY_DEFAULT="google-cloud-platform://?extra__google_cloud_platform__project=<YOUR PROJECT HERE>"
```

BigQueryOperator uses the "bigquery_default" connection. When not specified, local airflow uses an internal version of the connection which misses the property `project_id`. As you can see the connection string above provides the `project_id` property.

On startup Airflow loads environment variables that start with "AIRFLOW_" into memory. This mechanism can be used to override airflow properties and providing connections when running locally, as explained in the airflow documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables). Note this also works when running airflow directly without starting the web server.

So I have set up environments variables for all my connections, for example `AIRFLOW_CONN_MYSQL_DEFAULT`. I have put them into a .ENV file that get sourced from my IDE, but putting them into your .bash_profile would work fine too.

When you look inside your airflow instance on Cloud Composer, you see that the at the "bigquery_default" connection there has the `project_id`property set. That's why BigQueryOperator works when running through Cloud Composer.

(I am on airflow 1.10.2 and BigQuery 1.10.2)